# I need to validate first four digits in a phone number which should be "5678" in Node Js. How should i do it? Which Validator library should i use

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, express-validator, nodejs-stream

I need to validate the first four digits in a phone number which should be "5678" in nodeJs how should I do it. Which validator library should I use

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in [a minimal reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour of the site.

Comment: You don't need a library to do that, you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best practice to depends on external library only if you need it, in my opinion.

In your case, you can check if your phone number start with "5678" with a very simple regular expression:

```
const validate_phone = /^5678/

var phone_number = '5678122535'
console.log(validate_phone.test(phone_number))  // true

var phone_number = '1567812253'
console.log(validate_phone.test(phone_number))  // false
```

`^` stand for [matches beginning of input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret)

`test` stand for [executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: i did this:
if(number.charAt(0)==5 && number.charAt(1)==6 && number.charAt(2)==7 && number.charAt(3)==8 ){
        
    }
    else{
        return res.json('Number Should start with 5678')
    }

Comment: Yes, you can do that too.

Comment: I think you should now use this method even its correct since it lacks code readability.

Answer (score 0):

You could use substring function which is better then regular expression in terms of complexity.

```
const string = "56789012345" ;
string.substring(0,4)==="5678" ? true : false ;
```